# EKF node do not publish imu data but publish odometry. Humble

Tags: imu, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node, ekf-localization

I'm new using the robot localization package as you will see on my question below:

I'm using Humble with a Differential robot with 2 encoders and IMU wheeltec 9dof. I also have a GNSS but I wont integrate it.

Odometry is been publish by my controller and a Imu package is publishing /imu /imu/true_east and /magnetic_field. Check the output of my 2 sources:

```
/diff_cont/odom
    header:
  stamp:
    sec: 40
    nanosec: 468000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -7.950391677396397e-06
      y: -1.7468415794148058e-11
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 1.4804535484238412e-05
      w: 0.9999999998904129
  covariance:
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - more 0s
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 5.9768216141023505e-09
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 3.288518771417694e-08
  covariance:
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0-more 0s
```

/imu:

```
    header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1696860589
    nanosec: 511958241
  frame_id: imu
orientation:
  x: 0.0822714939713478
  y: -0.012695270590484087
  z: -0.9769877791404724
  w: -0.1963800191879273
orientation_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
angular_velocity:
  x: 0.0030348338186740875
  y: 0.011578499339520931
  z: 0.0029500082600861788
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
linear_acceleration:
  x: -0.2777896225452423
  y: -0.1351379007101059
  z: 9.706793785095215
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
```

This is my ekf config file:

```
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
        sensor_timeout: 0.1
        two_d_mode: true
        transform_time_offset: 0.0
        transform_timeout: 0.0
        print_diagnostics: true
        debug: false
        debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
        permit_corrected_publication: false
        publish_acceleration: false
        publish_tf: true
        
        map_frame: map            
        odom_frame: odom           
        base_link_frame: base_link
        world_frame: odom       
        imu_frame: imu


        odom0: odom
        odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                       false, false, false,
                       false, false, false,
                       false, false, true,
                       false, false, false]
        odom0_queue_size: 10
        odom0_differential: true  
        odom0_relative: false
        odom0_pose_use_child_frame: false
        odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
        odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

        imu0: imu
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                      false,  false,  true,
                      false, false, false,
                      false, false, false,
                      false, false, false]
        imu0_differential: false
        imu0_relative: false
        imu0_queue_size: 10

        use_control: false
        stamped_control: false
        control_timeout: 0.2
        control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
        acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
        deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
        acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
        deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Also, my Frame look like this (and I believe is correct)
[image]

I only want to fuse the odometry and and Z orientation from IMU to get a reliable POSE that I can use together with GNSS to navigate. The robot will be managed in 2D and outdoor.

When I run the EKF node, I see that the filtered odometry is being analized and giving me an output with the respective covariances (still didnt check is the data is reasonable), however the imu filtered data is not being published (but the topic is created).

EKF node info:

```
/ekf_filter_node
  Subscribers:
    /clock: rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock
    /imu: sensor_msgs/msg/Imu
    /odom: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /set_pose: geometry_msgs/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped
  Publishers:
    /diagnostics: diagnostic_msgs/msg/DiagnosticArray
    /odom: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
    /tf: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
  Service Servers:
    /ekf_filter_node/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
    /ekf_filter_node/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
    /ekf_filter_node/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
    /ekf_filter_node/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
    /ekf_filter_node/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
    /ekf_filter_node/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
    /enable: std_srvs/srv/Empty
    /reset: std_srvs/srv/Empty
    /set_pose: robot_localization/srv/SetPose
    /toggle: robot_localization/srv/ToggleFilterProcessing
```

My idea is: when I'm able to filter this imu data, I should make a transform with imu/filtered to base_link. So, when the motors are off but I move the robot manually, I can get a correct pose.

Questions:

1. What happen that EKF is not publishing imu data.
2. Do you know how to prepare this transform imu-base_link? any suggestion?
3. In general, Am I taking a good aproach?
4. any more info i can provide to any of you?

Comment: i don't think the EKF node is supposed to publish IMU data, It will take the odometry and IMU and publish the filtered odometry but I am not sure, you can take a look at the documentation [robot_localization docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above remark, EKF will have trouble dealing with 0 covariance data.
The whole point of an EKF is to estimate the most probable state given measurements and their covariance.
You should have some covariance both in the odometry and the IMU messages, maybe from the datasheet of your sensors.

Comment: Also your EKF node is subscribed to /odom but the odometry topic from your wheels should be diff_cont/odom so basically EKF is subscribing to the same topic it publishes.